# Issue creating project with mezzanine - shared hosting

Tags: python, shared-hosting, mezzanine

I'm trying to use Mezzanine cms in a shared hosting at 1and1. I installed a recent python version 3.3.2.

setup works well but when i try to create a project I got the following error message:

```
~/Mezzanine-1.4.16 > mezzanine-project blog
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/kunden/homepages/x/dxxxxxxx/htdocs/custom/bin/mezzanine-project", line 9, in 
    load_entry_point('Mezzanine==1.4.16', 'console_scripts', 'mezzanine-project')()
  File "/kunden/homepages/x/dxxxxxxx/htdocs/custom/lib/python3.3/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py3.3.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 345, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/kunden/homepages/x/dxxxxxxx/htdocs/custom/lib/python3.3/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py3.3.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2382, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/kunden/homepages/x/dxxxxxxx/htdocs/custom/lib/python3.3/site-packages/distribute-0.6.49-py3.3.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2088, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/kunden/homepages/x/dxxxxxxx/htdocs/custom/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Mezzanine-1.4.16-py3.3.egg/mezzanine/bin/mezzanine_project.py", line 9, in 
    from mezzanine.utils.importing import path_for_import
  File "/kunden/homepages/x/dxxxxxxx/htdocs/custom/lib/python3.3/site-packages/Mezzanine-1.4.16-py3.3.egg/mezzanine/utils/importing.py", line 23
    except (ValueError, ImportError, AttributeError), e:
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this ? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Current version of Mezzanine (1.4.16) doesn’t support Python 3. You have to use Python 2.6 / 2.7 ([Source: dependencies section in official docs](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/overview.html#dependencies)).

Answer (score 0):

Now supporting with Mezzanine 3.x